# Why `glmnet` is giving me number of variables x 100 as coefficient result?

Tags: r, glmnet

This is weird `dim(coef(fit1)) = [1] 1502  100`. 1502 is the number of variables. What is 100? I believe it is supposed to be 1. I expect the coefficient result 1502 x 1.

```
library(glmnet)
fit1 = glmnet(x_train, y_train)
dim(coef(fit1))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`glmnet` is providing the solutions for a sequence of values of $\lambda$, also called a *regularization path*.  One thing you can do is fit a model using `cv.glmnet`, get the value for $\lambda$ which minimizes the cross validation empirical loss (it's the `lambda.min` element of your model object) and then use the set of $\beta$ estimates corresponding to this value of $\lambda$.